# C++ Taking data from a text file into int Vector

Tags: c++

I have an assignment from college where I have a text file with multiple values.
They are on different lines and I have to take them and store them in a Vector.
We also have to use a Class that has ifstream, ofstream and an int Vector already set up, but these are in the private section of the Class and I can not seem to use them (not allowed to change the class!).
We took the values in via getline but now need to convert them from strings to int but the problem is that we are not allowed to add more libraries.
The libraries we are allowed to use are:

`iostream`
`string`
`fstream`
`vector`

Any help in converting these would be much appreciated!

Here is the brief:

> Program 1
>
> Write a program that contains a class that meets the following
>   declaration (i.e. this declaration should be put at the top of your
>   cpp file):
>
> Your program should read sales values from a file called ‘sales.txt’
>   and outputs a bar graph representing these values to a file called
>   ‘graph.txt’. Create each bar in the bar graph by displaying a row of
>   asterisks. Each asterisk should represent £100 of sales.
>
> For example, ‘sales.txt’ file contained these values:
>
> ```
> 1000
> 500
> 1200
> 600
> 200
> ```
>
> Here is what the ‘graph.txt’ file should contain after the program is
>   executed:
>
> ```
> SALES BAR CHART
> (each * equals £100)
> Store 1: **********
> Store 2: *****
> Store 3: ************
> Store 4: ******
> Store 5: **
> ```

And here is the class we are not allowed to alter:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class SalesData
{
private:
ifstream inputfile;
ofstream outputfile;
vector<int> salesrecords;
public:
void loadDataFromFile(string filename);
void saveBarChartToFile(string filename);
};
```

I have completely skipped the class now and created new ifstream/ofstream and vectors.
The output I have working fine its the input that I am struggling with!

```
void loadDataFromFile()
{
    ifstream inputfile;
    vector<int> salenumbers;
    int holder;

    inputfile.open("sales.txt");

    if (!inputfile.is_open())
    {
         cout << "Text Not Open Error!";
    }
    else
    {
        string line;
        vector<string> text;
        int i = 0;



        while (inputfile.good())
        {
            getline(inputfile, line);
            text[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
        for (int z = 0; z <= 5; z++)
        {
             int num = atoi(text.at(z).c_str());
             salenumbers.push_back(num);
        }



    }
    inputfile.close();

    saveBarChartToFile(salenumbers);
}
```

I have tried multiple ways like til eof, just taking it straight into an int vector and they havent worked. I found many ways to change the string to an int but it required more libraries.

Also if I could make use of the class it would make it easier.

I was going to make a new question but it wont let me so adding it on to this one:

I had a Function to output to a file that I was testing with cout and it was working fine printing to the screen. Now I have changed it to output to a file but nothing is coming up in the file.

Was wondering if anyone could see the mistake:

```
void saveBarChartToFile(vector<int>numbers)
{
    ofstream outputfile;

    outputfile.open("graph.txt", std::ios_base::app);


    if (!outputfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "FILE NOT OPEN ERROR!";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            int stars = 0;
            int starAmount = numbers[i] / 100;
            outputfile << "Shop" << (i + 1) << ":";
            for (int j = 0; j < starAmount; j++)
            {
                outputfile << "*";
            }
            outputfile << "/n";
        }
        outputfile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than "I can not seem to use them"? It's very difficult to see from here what your code looks like.

Comment: can you show us the class provided to you

Comment: you can convert from string to int using 
string str = "123";
int numb;
istringstream ( str ) >> numb;

Comment: But if you can't use more headers, just omit strings; load data directly into `int` variable (like `file >> myInteger`).

Comment: Debugging code from a *textual description* is not as easy as it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should directly read the integers.

```
int sale;
vector<int> salenumbers;
while (inputfile >> sale)
{
    salesnumbers.push_back(sale)
}
```

This should keep reading in the integers and saving them until the end of the file.
Give a try to this logic instead of the block

```
string line;
vector<string> text;
int i = 0;

while (inputfile.good())
{
     getline(inputfile, line);
     text[i] = line;
     i++;
}
for (int z = 0; z <= 5; z++)
{
     int num = atoi(text.at(z).c_str());
     salenumbers.push_back(num);
}
```

Regarding the new "question".
I can generate the file and its content is for example in my case:

Shop1:****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/nShop2:********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/nShop3:************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/n

using this test code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  vector<int> sale;
  sale.push_back(40000);
  sale.push_back(50000);
  sale.push_back(60000);
  saveBarChartToFile(sale);

}
```

Comment: That worked! Me and a buddy have been scratching our heads on this forever!

Could you explain that snippet to me a bit better please as I am sure I will need this again in the future!

Comment: Sure! You want to read the all file as long as integers are present in that file and basically that's what the line "while (inputfile >> sale)" is telling. As long as you read a valid integers, save the current one you just read, save it in the vector of all the salesnumbers ("salenumbers.push_back(sale);") move forward in the file and check the next.
Now, I'm not sure you need extra checks before that, but as long as you have checked that the file is opened ok ("if (!inputfile.is_open())") it should be ok in this simple case.

Comment: I have another problem now. I was testing my output function with cout to see if it was printing out (which it was) but it does not seem to print to the file!
Here is the function:

Comment: void saveBarChartToFile(vector<int>numbers)
{
 ofstream outputfile;

 outputfile.open("graph.txt", std::ios_base::app);


 if (!outputfile.is_open())
 {
  cout << "FILE NOT OPEN ERROR!";
 }
 else
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
  {
   int stars = 0;
   int starAmount = numbers[i] / 100;
   outputfile << "Shop" << (i + 1) << ":";
   for (int j = 0; j < starAmount; j++)
   {
    outputfile << "*";
   }
   outputfile << "/n";
  }
  outputfile.close();
 }
}

Comment: as you can see from my edit, for me it generates the file.

Comment: Yeah I found the problem, it was not creating the file in the right directory. 
I set the right directory now to find the file and it all works now!
Again thank you for your help it is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad! Hope the answer was useful for you overall!